# How can i get the value like distance from a iframe map from a new window opened using window.open?

Tags: javascript, iframe, maps

I have a new window containing a iframe google map which opens using window.open() method.I want the value of distance(km) from the iframe map?

I have tried with popUpWindow.document.getElementById('map').value. But it consoles that it is undefined.

HTML.

```
<iframe id="map" src=""> </iframe>
```

The src for the iframe is a google maps api with origin and destination.

JS.

```
var map = popUpWindow.document.getElementById('map').value;
console.log('map',map);
```

I want the value from the iframe google map.

Note: The iframe is in a new window , a child window.

Comment: I don't know much about Google Map but there seem to be an API for such request. So maybe you can take your iframe as a Google map object in javascript, like `var service = new google.maps...` and use the service described here [Google maps Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_parsing_the_results)

Comment: @Paul I am getting the distance in the map. I just need to access the iframe dom and get the value.Is there any other way?

Comment: @Paul atlast i ended up using Google maps distance matrix to get the distance. I couldn't access the iframe dom. So, i ended up with your suggestion. Thank You.